# Something failed, the API cannot share any more information at the time of the request

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

We are receiving below  error when we are querying pages under a specific section. What could be the cause?

"{\r\n  \"error\":{\r\n    \"code\":\"19999\",\"message\":\"Something failed, the API cannot share any more information at the time of the request.\",\"@api.url\":\"http://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C19999\"\r\n  }\r\n}"

X-CorrelationId: 751e59b7-6f5b-463e-8bcc-1f3f8d4998ff  X-UserSessionId: bb944d36-87f3-4249-8033-610a5b661c05 
Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2016 02:48:36 GMT

Answer (score 0):

I receive the same error when the page-id is incorrect in the **Get page** request

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/notes/pages/<id>/content

Perhaps check the pages available under the appropriate section via Microsoft Graph explorer